Fantasy action manhwa where the MC inherits abilities from his parents and trains with them individually without the other knowing
The main character's parents have like hidden races or abilities that awaken when you get to a certain age. And the MC inherits the abilities from both parents and then proceeds to train one with the dad while the mother doesn't know and the opposite.

It is "genius of unique lineage".
Gwang Ik is the main character of the manhwa. His father is immortal and mother is a shapeshifter. He trains with father's friend who is an immortal (trains to heal his body when cut) and trains with his mother's friend who fights with him and trains his strength and stamina.

